# awk - regex to print first matching group

Tags: awk, ksh

I am trying to get the first matching group based on regex, but it's not printing anything after the second `awk` command. Not sure what I was doing wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
git status | awk 'NR=1' --> Limiting this t0 print the first line.
On branch TA1692959
```

```
git status | awk 'NR=1' | awk '/^On\sbranch\s([\w]*)/{ print $1 }' --> I was trying to get the first word "TA1692959" after "On branch"this prints nothing.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git status |

{n,m,g}awk 'NR<--NF' FS='^On branch |[^[:alnum:]_].+$' OFS=

TA1241521
```

Answer (score 0):

If you find yourself passing the data through multiple `awk` calls then chances are pretty good you can do the same thing with a single `awk` call, eg:

```
git status | awk 'NR==1 && /^On branch / {print $3; exit}'
TA1692959
```

In this case:

- there's no need for a regex; otherwise OP should update the question with additional samples showing the need for a regex
- the `exit` is optional and merely allows `awk` to skip processing the rest of the input stream